# Setting dropdownlist selecteditem programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to set the `selecteditem` attribute for an ASP.Net dropdownlist control programmatically.

So I want to pass a value to the dropdownlist control to set the selected item where the item is equal to the passed value.

Comment: Do you mean `myList.SelectedValue = someStringValue;`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Assuming the list is already data bound you can simply set the `SelectedValue` property on your dropdown list.

```
list.DataSource = GetListItems(); // <-- Get your data from somewhere.
list.DataValueField = "ValueProperty";
list.DataTextField = "TextProperty";
list.DataBind();

list.SelectedValue = myValue.ToString();
```

The value of the `myValue` variable would need to exist in the property specified within the `DataValueField` in your controls databinding.

**UPDATE**:
If the value of `myValue` doesn't exist as a value with the dropdown list options it will default to select the first option in the dropdown list.

Comment: No, SelectedValue is not read-only: "Gets the value of the selected item in the list control, or selects the item in the list control that contains the specified value."

Comment: This did just work for me, it chose which element should be pre-selected base on what value I gave `.SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 63):

`ddlData.SelectedIndex` will contain the `int` value To select the specific value into `DropDown` :

```
ddlData.SelectedIndex=ddlData.Items.IndexOf(ddlData.Items.FindByText("value"));
```

`return` type of `ddlData.Items.IndexOf(ddlData.Items.FindByText("value"));` is `int`.

Answer (score 28):

Here is the code I was looking for :

```
DDL.SelectedIndex = DDL.Items.IndexOf(DDL.Items.FindByText("PassedValue"));
```

Or

```
DDL.SelectedIndex = DDL.Items.IndexOf(DDL.Items.FindByValue("PassedValue"));
```

Comment: That's basically doing the same thing with more code.  Even if the selected value doesn't exist as an item in the list it defaults to the first option as its selected value.

Answer (score 5):

Well if I understood correctly your question. The Solution for setting the value for a given dropdownlist will be:

```
dropdownlist1.Text="Your Value";
```

This will work only if the value is existing in the data-source of the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to select your list item based on an expression:

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in list.Items)
{
    listItem.Selected = listItem.Value.Contains("some value");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just Use this oneliner:

```
divisions.Items.FindByText("Some Text").Selected = true;
divisions.Items.FindByValue("some value").Selected = true;
```

where divisions is a dropdownlist control.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: You helped me , thanks you very much for this

Answer (score 1):

```
var index = ctx.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => Equals(item.Value, Settings.Default.Format_Encoding));
ctx.SelectedIndex = ctx.Items.IndexOf(index);
```

OR

```
foreach (var listItem in ctx.Items)
  listItem.Selected = Equals(listItem.Value as Encoding, Settings.Default.Format_Encoding);
```

Should work.. especially when using extended RAD controls in which FindByText/Value doesn't even exist!

Answer (score 1):

```
ddList.Items.FindByText("oldValue").Selected = false;
ddList.Items.FindByText("newValue").Selected = true;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To make your answer bett - add some comments to a code you posted. Posting a block of code without any explanations is not a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

On load of My Windows Form the `comboBox` will display the `ClassName` column of my `DataTable` as it's the `DisplayMember` also has its `ValueMember` (not visible to user) with it.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.comboBoxSubjectCName.DataSource = this.Student.TableClass;
                this.comboBoxSubjectCName.DisplayMember = TableColumn.ClassName;//Column name that will be the DisplayMember
                this.comboBoxSubjectCName.ValueMember = TableColumn.ClassID;//Column name that will be the ValueMember
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Safety check to only select if an item is matched.

```
//try to find item in list.  
ListItem oItem = DDL.Items.FindByValue("PassedValue"));
//if exists, select it.
if (oItem != null) oItem.Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the best solution

> drpGroups.SelectedValue = drpGroups.Items[0].Value.ToString();

Answer (score -1):

```
            ddlemployee.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddlemployee.DataTextField = "Employee Name";
            ddlemployee.DataValueField = "RecId";
            ddlemployee.DataBind();
            ddlemployee.Items.Insert(0, "All");
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_