# How to programmatically set SelectedValue of Dropdownlist when it is bound to XmlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, xmldatasource

I'm using `XmlDataSource` as the `datasource` for a `dropdownlist`.

Now I want to set the `SelectedValue` of the drop down when the page initially loads. I have tried the `OnDataBound event` of the drop down in which I could see the total items. But setting the `SelectedValue` didn't work. In`OnDataBinding` event, I couldn't even see the total items probably because the list isn't bound yet?

How can I set the selected index based on a value?

Comment: Are you using declarative or programmatic databinding? More specifically, is your dropdown list already populated at the point where you want to set the SelectedValue?

Comment: No, the dropdownlist was not populated because I want to set the SelectedValue in the Page_Load.

Comment: Have you tried, after calling DataBind on your DropDownList, to do something like ddl.SelectedIndex = 0 ?

Comment: One solution is to programmatically databind the dropdown list before you set the selected value. You might also find an event in the ASP.NET page life cycle that occurs after declarative databinding happens.

Comment: That worked. I was trying binding events, but never tried to call DataBind directly on the dropdownlist. But when I did, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Posting my comment as an answer.

Comment: I just set the SelectedIndex in page load, no need to data bind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting dropdownlist selecteditem programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496456/setting-dropdownlist-selecteditem-programmatically)

Answer (score 79):

This seems to work for me.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataBind(); // get the data into the list you can set it
            DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("SOMECREDITPROBLEMS").Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(stringValue).Selected = true;
```

should work.

Answer (score 11):

This is working code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            { 
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "user_name";
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "user_id";
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = getData();// get the data into the list you can set it
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();

    DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("your default selected text"));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried, after calling DataBind on your DropDownList, to do something like ddl.SelectedIndex = 0 ?

Comment: Consider formatting this answer- besides it is wrong(or not entirely what the OP asked about). Just remove it.