# Trying to set the value of a Drop Down

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set the value or text of a drop down to a value being pulled by the database, this is being passed through an Entity and when I debug i see the right hand side part of the code has the string value i want to match on the drop down but still when I do a step in and goes to the next line the left hand side still selects the -- Select -- item

I am trying to assign it as follows

```
ddlMyDropDown.SelectedItem.Text = Clients.MerchandiseType.ToString();
```

WHEN STEPPING THROUGH IT

```
ddlMyDropDown.SelectedItem.Text contains "--Select --"
Clients.MerchandiseType.ToString() contains "Sporting Goods"
```

ddlMyDropDown has an Item named "Sporting Goods" but it never selects it when I use the code above , I am not sure why. Is there anyway to achieve this?

I am not trying to change change any values , but to set the ddlMyDropDown to the Text in Clients.MerchandiseType.ToString(). The drop down will always have the text being passed on Clients.Merchandise.ToString();

Thank you

Comment: It's not really clear from your question whether you want to change the selected `ListItem` or you want to change its Text property.

Comment: I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496456/setting-dropdownlist-selecteditem-programmatically

Comment: This is an indirect answer to your question...

I think the problem you might be running into is you are trying to have your View Model drive how your View renders the data. Have you considered handling that through the ViewModel?

Have a property called SelectedItem (or something) and bind the drop-down selected item to it in your XAML.

Comment: You're not selecting the item in this example. This example simply changes the text of the item that's already selected. See my example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the method names at the moment as i'm not at a pc with visual studios but here's some hints.

```
var text = Clients.MerchandiseType.ToString();
var item = ddlMyDropDown.Find(text); //Some method that returns a list item
ddlMyDropDown.SelectedItem = item;
```

Hope this helps.

If theres not a better answer tomorrow I will post a full solution.

Comment: This will not work. SelectedItem is read only and without some type of null checking, this solution is prone to exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ddlMyDropDown.SelectedIndex = Combox1.FindStringExact(Clients.MerchandiseType.ToString());
```

Not sure but I think you can't change the Selected Item by changing SelectedText.

Comment: This will not work. You're setting the SelectedIndex in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set

```
ddlMyDropDown.SelectedIndex = i
```

or

```
ddlMyDropDown.SelectedItem = item
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following:

```
ddlMyDropDown.SelectedValue = Clients.MerchandiseType.ToString();
```

OR

```
ListItem item = ddlMyDropDown.Items.FindItemByValue(Clients.MerchandiseType.ToString());
if (item != null)
   item.Selected = true;
```

Comment: Can I find it by text?, right now the value is "0" but my text is "Sporting Goods" when I test,... I need to select the item where the text = "Sporting Goods" in the drop down