# Can a Gridview be populated even without using postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

this is my second option [regarding my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596600/c-sharp-2nd-dropdown-list-cant-retain-the-selected-item) I did a lot of searching in google and tried it for a couple of times. Do you think its possible to **populate a gridview without any postback from a dropdownlist**?

Comment: If you want to persist it across postbacks, no. How do you want to populate a GridView from a DropDownList?

Comment: @TimSchmelter here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596600/c-sharp-2nd-dropdown-list-cant-retain-the-selected-item .. thats my main prob ., and this question is just my second option.. Thank you ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need postback in some form traditionally or using AJAX. These kinds of things happen in the server and that is why you need postback. Or you can use extensive Javascript.

Comment: _"Or you can use extensive Javascript"_ You can populate the gridview on clientside, but all changes would be lost on postback on server.

Comment: Thank you ^___^ I'll try that ajax and javascript. :) ei, would you try my first prob ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596600/c-sharp-2nd-dropdown-list-cant-retain-the-selected-item preeeetty pleaaaase ^____^.. thank you @iefpw

Answer (score 2):

Use update panel and script manager. Change properties of update panel Update mod conditional. After you can call when you want "updatepanel.Update()" or select your trigers and it ll do it automaticly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript and draw the whole gridview since a gridview is a table with columns and rows.