# catch a error: is not in list

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, selectedvalue

how can I catch this error?

```
DropdownList1.SelectedValue = strText;
```

This is the error:

> Selected Value of DropdownList1 is invalid because it does not appear in the list of items.

Can I catch it with something like strText exist in dropdownlist1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DropDownList.Items.FindByValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
if( ItemCollection.FindByValue(strText) != null)
{
    DropdownList1.SelectedValue = strText;
}
```

Comment: I change the dropdownlist values by databind but then is strText not exits in the dropdownlist, sorry for my bad english

Comment: To set SelectedValue you should have given value in one of listitems of dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 DropdownList1.SelectedIndex =    
                  DropdownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropdownList1.Items.FindByValue(strText));
```

References 
[Setting dropdownlist selecteditem programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496456/setting-dropdownlist-selecteditem-programmatically)