# Setting dropdownlist selected index

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist with country names in alphabetical order. I want the dropdown to  have (show) India as the default value always. I don't want to set the selected index with a constant because other countries may be added to the list later. How can set the index to "India"?

```
 ddlCountryCode.DataSource = ds1.Tables["AUser"];
 ddlCountryCode.DataTextField = "CountryCode";
 ddlCountryCode.SelectedIndex = 
             ddlCountryCode.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountryCode.Items.FindByText("India(+91)"));
 ddlCountryCode.DataBind();
```

doesnt work...

Comment: retagged: `html.dropdownlistfor` is used in MVC. Please use necessary tags

Answer (score 8):

You can use like this

```
 DropdownList1.SelectedIndex =    
                  DropdownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropdownList1.Items.FindByValue(strText));
```

or

```
DropdownList1.SelectedIndex =    
                  DropdownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropdownList1.Items.FindByText(strText));
```

References 
[Setting dropdownlist selecteditem programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496456/setting-dropdownlist-selecteditem-programmatically)

### Edit 1

Change the sequence of your code

```
ddlCountryCode.DataSource = ds1.Tables["AUser"];
ddlCountryCode.DataTextField = "CountryCode";
ddlCountryCode.DataBind();

ddlCountryCode.SelectedIndex = 
         ddlCountryCode.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountryCode.Items.FindByText("India(+91)"));
```

Comment: *india* is where in the text or the value of the drop down list?

Comment: this is case sensitive take care of this.

Comment: **use this after data bind** ddlCountryCode.SelectedIndex = ddlCountryCode.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountryCode.Items.FindByText("India(+91)"));

Answer (score 4):

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "India";
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Index after DataBind(). Data Bind Binds Items in 'ddlCountryCode.Items' So you can Select index of 'india' one items exists with ddlCountryCode.

```
DropdownList1.Items is a list so u can use IndexOf()

 ddlCountryCode.DataSource = ds1.Tables["AUser"];
 ddlCountryCode.DataTextField = "CountryCode";
 ddlCountryCode.DataBind();
 ddlCountryCode.SelectedIndex = 
 ddlCountryCode.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountryCode.Items.FindByText("India(+91)"));
```