# How to automatically select a dropdownlist item based on the item's Text?

Tags: c#

I have saved `leaveID`, `leavename` and `type name` into my database.

Now I want to fill leave name(textbox) and type name(dropdownlist) automatically, when I select `leaveID`. The thing is when I select dropdownlist `LeaveID`, Leave Name(textbox) fills automatically but typename(dropdown list) not fills. my `ddlid_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler is,

```
protected void ddlid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "select leavename from LeaveType where leaveID='" + 
                 ddlid.SelectedItem.Text + "'";

    SqlDataReader dr = conn.query(str);
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        txtid.Text = dr[0].ToString();//VALUE FILLS AUTOMATICALLY ACCORDING TO SELECTED ID
    }

    string str1 = "select TypeName from Leavetype where LeaveID='"+
                  ddlid.SelectedItem.Text+"'";

    SqlDataReader dr1 = conn.query(str1);
    if (dr1.Read())
    {
        ddltype.SelectedItem.Text= dr1[0].ToString();//VALUE NOT FILLS AUTOMATICALLY ACCORDING TO SELECTED ID
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Have you debug your code? What is your `dr1[0]` looks like in debugger? And would be better to use `ExecuteScalar` in your case which returns first column of the first row as an `object`.

Comment: Your question is confusing. According to your title, you want to fill a dropdown list, but your code shows you trying to set the selected value based upon the selection in another dropdown list. Also, your code shows the ddlid_SelectedIndexChanged event handler, not a button click.  Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496456/setting-dropdownlist-selecteditem-programmatically

Comment: Sorry Matty M, not button click it is ddlid_SelectedIndexChanged event handler. yes when I select leave id from from droppdownlist I want to fill leave name and type name automatically. I have already add this values in databse now it is for updation..

Comment: @DwaneMarsh Is the value you're pulling back in dr1[0] already in the dropdown list items collection?

Comment: Yes Matty M it is already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ddlType.SelectedValue = ddlType.Items.FindByText(dr1[0].ToString()).Value;
```

Also, you should take Soner's advice about using parameterized queries in order to defend against Sql injection attacks.