# Dropdownlist value and text set not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, dropdown

```cs
DataTable dtPosition = PositionManager.GetPositionByName(institutionName);
if(dtPosition != null && dtPosition.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int positionId = Convert.ToInt32(dtPosition.Rows[0]["PositionID"].ToString());
    string positionName = dtPosition.Rows[0]["PositionName"].ToString();
    ddlPosition.SelectedValue = positionId.ToString();
    ddlPosition.Text = positionName;

}
```

Through my `dtPosition` dataTable, I am fetching `positionName` and `PositionId`, which is successfully loading on positionId and PositionName variables. But when I'm trying to set the value and text of my `ddlPosition` dropdownList, it is not working. There is no error also.

I want `positionId` and `positionName` to be the value and text of `ddlPosition`. Would you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Is the above being executed on Page_Load()?

Comment: No. Why should I executed this in page Load? Can you explain? 
And is this the right process I am doing  to set the value of ddlPosition?

Comment: No this executing inside ddlInstitution_SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: The control is not bound so you can't set SelectedValue directly by code. Find the index of the element and set SelectedIndex instead. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3499545/2516718).

Comment: I think that's your problem, the `ddlInstitution_SelectedIndexChanged` event is only fired when the control's value is changed on the client side. You need to set the value on `Page_Load()` but it's worth making sure that you prevent this default value from being set during a `PostBack`. Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

If ddlposition is empty just add the item on the fly

```
 //put the positionId and Name in a list item
 ListItem item = new ListItem(positionName, positionId.ToString());
  ddlPosition.Items.Add(item);
  
  // you may need to call ddlPosition.Databound();

 //then if needed set the selected value
 ddlPosition.SelectedValue = positionID.ToString();
```