# How does one use a selected value on a drop down list when some value come back as null?

Tags: c#, datatable, selectedvalue

**Objective:** To have drop down list select a specific value based on some data on a data table

**Issue:** Some of the data on the datatable does not have a value and this results in an out of range exception the code is as follows

```
dtMyDataTable = objMyObject.MyStoredProcedure();

if(dtMyDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   ddlMyDropDownList = dtMyDataTable.Rows[0]["OptionalField"].ToString();
}
```

Thank you in advance for any comments, suggestions or recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested this is how I resolved my issue:

```
       if (dtMyTable.Rows[0]["OptionalField"] != null)
            {
                if (dtMyTable.Rows[0]["OptionalField"].ToString() == "")
                {
                    ddlMyDropDownList .SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    ddlMyDropDownList .SelectedValue = dtMyTable.Rows[0]["OptionalField"].ToString();
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(dtMyDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   if(dtMyDataTable.Rows[0]["OptionalField"] != null)
       ddlMyDropDownList = dtMyDataTable.Rows[0]["OptionalField"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: This works when the I have a value that isn't null, however when I come across null values I get an exception that says the ddl Selected Value is out range. I tried creating an else that sets the ddl SelectedValue to "0", but it doesn't seem to resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

Is ddlMyDropDownList the dropdown list control?  If so, you can't assign a string value to a list control.  So that might be a problem.  See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249394/how-to-select-a-dropdown-list-item-by-value-programatically) for how to do that.

That answer should also show you how to prevent against a null value.