# dropdownlist error in c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to show a value in DropDownList at page load and the value is "1 Year".
here is my Database Table

```
id  instal
0   Choose
6   6 Month
12  1 Year
24  2 Year
36  3 Year
```

here is my ASPX code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="instal" DataValueField="id" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:paconn %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [cms_instal] ORDER BY [id]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

and its my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList1.Text = "1 Year";
    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

but problem is that when my page is loaded it gives an error
"'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value"

i am using ASP.Net C#, SQL Server 2008.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to SELECT a dropdown list item by value programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249394/how-to-select-a-dropdown-list-item-by-value-programatically)

Comment: you can try this DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text = "1 Year";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` property of a DropDownList gets or sets the `SelectedValue`. Since your `DataValueField` is set to "id", you would need to set the `Text` property to "12".

Answer (score 0):

Move the text to the [LoadComplete event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList1.Text = "1 Year"; 
    }
```

The list binding has not occurred in page load so the list is not able to take another value which is not in the list. Setting the value after page load will allow it to use an existing value.

Comment: You need to set the value after load event or after the control has binded properly as the list binding has not completed. So it needs to load up the values from the datasoure to allow it set a value from the list. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx