# Dynamically populated DropDownList setting SelectedIndex changes both DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to set the selected index or value of two `DropDownList` that are populated from an array.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ListItem[] jobs;
            List<ListItem> data = new List<ListItem> {
                new ListItem("Hello", "World"),
                new ListItem("new", "item"),
                new ListItem("next", "item2"),
                new ListItem("four", "four")
            };
            jobs = (from x in data
                    select new ListItem(x.Text, x.Value)).ToArray();
            // jobs is any array of list items where
            // text = value or text != value, but value is unique.
            DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(jobs);
            DropDownList2.Items.AddRange(jobs);
            DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 1;
            DropDownList2.SelectedValue = jobs[3].Value;
        }
    }
```

On the actual page both `DropDownList` have *"four"* selected. How can I set different values?
Note: I know using linq is not needed here, but in the project code *data* is from a SQL DB.

Comment: Take a look here, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249394/how-to-select-a-dropdown-list-item-by-value-programatically][1]

The selected value needs to be a string.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249394/how-to-select-a-dropdown-list-item-by-value-programatically

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'm thinking I need a deep copy of each ListItem. Would it be cheaper to repeat the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Items.AddRange(array)` preforms a shallow copy of array.

to preform a deep copy change

```
DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(jobs);
```

to

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = jobs;     

DropdownList1.DataBind();
```

repeat for the other list.

Answer (score 1):

Create another ListItem jobsClone

```
ListItem[] jobsClone = new ListItem[jobs.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < jobs.Length; i++)
{
    jobsClone[i] = new ListItem(jobs[i].Value);
}
```

then You can set your SelectedIndex

```
DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(jobs);
DropDownList2.Items.AddRange(jobsClone);
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 1;
DropDownList2.SelectedIndex = 3;
```