# How to select a prepopulated dropdownlist option in a popup before showing from code-behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

This line sets the selected index to the correct number:

```
    ddlCliNewMsg.SelectedIndex = ddlCliNewMsg.Items.IndexOf(ddlCliNewMsg.Items.FindByValue(dr["ClientText"].ToString()));
```

But when the popup loads, the 0 index is selected.

Comment: Can you please share the code where dropdown list is being populated?

Comment: Added the code which populates the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
    if (dr["ClientText"].ToString().Length > 0)
    {
    ddlCliNewMsg.SelectedValue = dr["ClientText"].ToString();
    }
```

To

```
    if (dr["ClientText"].ToString().Length > 0)
    {
    ddlCliNewMsg.ClearSelection(); //making sure the previous selection has been cleared
    ddlCliNewMsg.Items.FindByValue(dr["ClientText"].ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
```

Comment: Does it matter that the button  that invokes the popup is inside a UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for populating dropdownlist use below code:

ddlCliNewMsg.DataSource = dataSource;
ddlCliNewMsg.DataTextField = textField;
ddlCliNewMsg.DataValueField = valueField;
ddlCliNewMsg.DataBind();

    textField and valueField is data field for text and value of dropdownlist.
    for selecting item with your value use below code:

 ddlCliNewMsg.Items.FindByValue("your value").Selected = true;

    replace your value with "your value"
```

Comment: When the page loads I am already populating the dropdownlist. Updated my question to show how I am populating the dropdownlist. I am just looking to set the selecteditem of the prepopulated dropdownlist to that of the `ClientText` col.