# Function to get value from dropdownlist item

Tags: c#, html-select

I have a dropdownlist bound to a database, and I have a label.

I have to set the label text equal to a dropdownlist item text, based on its item value.

I need to find a function that works with the dropdownlist item values. I tried the following code but it only works with the item index instead of its value.

```
lbcentro.Text = DDLCentroC.Items[15].Text;
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249394/how-to-select-a-dropdown-list-item-by-value-programatically

Comment: I don't need a dropdownlist to have a selected value

Comment: In that case, the answer you have posted is a good, compact solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
        lbcentro.Text = DDLCentroC.Items.FindByValue("15").Text;
```

is there any other solution?